# how to resolve Jboss deployment error?

Tags: deployment, jboss

```
17:19:30,298 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of
incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/ROOT" is missing the following dependenc
ies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/Test" is missing the following dependenc
ies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/admin-console" is missing the following
dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jbossws" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jmx-console" is missing the following de
pendencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/web-console" is missing the following de
pendencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): LifecycleEx
ception:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Addres
s already in use: JVM_Bind /127.0.0.1:8009
  Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following reas
on(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **

17:19:30,298 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=
JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 56s:184ms
```

Hi Can you guys guide me through how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the logs:

> Address already in use: JVM_Bind /127.0.0.1:8009

Something else is already listening on port 8009. You need to stop that other process before JBoss can start.