# DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR in jboss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss5.x

```
09:44:31,717 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/Pojo1" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/Pojo2" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/PojoSRD" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/admin-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jbossws" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jmx-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/srdlogistics" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")   Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/web-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:   Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:8080   Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **

09:44:31,718 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 55s:762ms
```

Can anyone tell me what is Deployment error and how to solve it?

Comment: The answer is in the logs. Find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968721/how-to-resolve-jboss-deployment-error?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

Your logging states the following:

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:8080

Something is already running on port 8080. Maybe another instance of JBoss is already running?